# How to keep only open apps in Dock in macOS Mojave?

Tags: mac, macos-mojave

In previous iterations of macOS you could issue the command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool TRUE; killall Dock
```

To have the dock auto remove closed apps without having to manually quit them. This command doesn't seem to work on macOS Mojave (10.14.4).

Does anyone know how I'd go about issuing the equivalent command for this macOS Mojave?

Comment: "without having to manually quit them"?? If you don't quit an app, it's still running & will be shown in the Dock. Closing all windows does not Quit most apps.

Comment: That's the point of the command. In previous versions of the OS issuing that command configured the dock so that simply pressing the red x would close the window, quit the app, and remove it from the dock as though you dragged it off manually.

Comment: I'd like to see some citation for that.

Comment: That's off topic. If you don't know that's fine. I've used it in previous versions of the OS to configure workflow. Hopefully another power user comes by. If not I'll update when I figure it out.

Comment: @Tetsujin https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481024/how-do-i-undo-defaults-write-com-apple-dock-static-only-bool-true-killall-doc and many others, found with a quick web search.

Comment: @slhck - yes, I know the command - it doesn't explain the claim that it will, in effect, auto-quit on close last window.